# How to obtain credentials for Http Basic Authentiction

Tags: c#, windows, http

I'm writing a C# application and need to scrape some information from an rss page that only offers Http Basic Authentication.

This seems to leave me with two choices

- Ask the user to input their credentials into my app (which has trust issues as the app is then a potential middleman attacker?)
- Get windows to insert the credentials on behalf of my app somehow (does this facility exist?)

All the examples I've seen on SO have the username/password hardcoded in the app or passed in as parameters from somewhere unspecified. My use-case is I'd like to give this app to people who may not want to trust it with their password.

How is this usually handled? Thanks

Comment: Is this a native application or a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** It is not possible with basic auth. It is generally not possible with the OS a the trusted instance.

**Long answer:**

The proper way to solve this would involve a procedure where your application hands control to the OS (Windows), which then asks the user "Do you trust application XY to use your identity?". After user acceptance, your application would receive a security token which you could use afterwards to make your HTTP request to get the RSS feed. The problem is, that the site in question does only accept basic auth. This means, that the "security token" is the base64-encoded username and password. So the username and password would be exposed to your application anyway.

The second problem is that the OS and the RSS site have to share a secret (i.e. an encryption key not available to you or anyone else not allowed to log in site users), to enable the OS to issue a secure token that is trusted by the RSS site.

*How the problem can actually be solved*

The default, real-world example for the access of web resources with third-party software on behalf of the user without knowing his password is [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), see for example the [Facebook login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow). (However, this requires the website/resource in question to provide third-party access. As your question indicates, this does not apply for your use case.)

The pattern employed is the following:

Prerequisite: You need to register your application with the RSS service provider to obtain an application ID and an application secret.

1. Your application redirects the user to the login endpoint of the identity provider.
2. The user accepts (or declines) the access of your application to his identity and data (e.g. the RSS stream).
3. The identity provider redirects to your app
4. Your application receives a token which can be used to make authenticated requests on behalf of the user. This may involve additional steps like exchanging the token for another.

*Alternative Solution (does not answer your question):*
Sometimes (protected) RSS feeds can be accessed via secret user-specific URLs. Of course, the user would have to provide your application with that url.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed :)